# How to get debug mode for CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :debug => Rails.env.development? %>
```

Doesn't seem like its working. I think the asset is still being precompiled... I can verify this because firebug ain't reporting the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may not have this option set in your development.rb file:

`config.assets.debug = true`

With this on Rails will render a link (or script) tag for each file. You don't need a :debug option in your layout file unless you want to turn debug mode off (=> false).

See the Rails guide on [using the pipeline in development mode](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development) for more information.

Comment: I Added `config.assets.debug = true` in initializers/development.rb. Refreshed the page and it seems that CSS is still being compiled

Comment: Check the Rails guide for the correct settings for each of the environment files - something may be wrong elsewhere. Also do a forced refresh of your browser - stuff may be cached.